# Solving ODE set with a step-function parameter using odeint

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system numerically with odeint in Python:[image]:

My problem is that k1 depends on the value of p. When `p<=0.01` `k1=0` and otherwise `k1=5`.

I'm not sure how to write the system with the above constraint. I can start with:

```
def sys(x,t,flip):
S,T,p = x

dx = [1-T-k1*T,
     0.1*(1-S)-k1*S,
     -0.2*(1-T-k1*T)+0.1*(1-S)-k1*S]
return dx
```

Where `flip` can be the `0.01` value, but I'm not sure how to implement the if statement for this case, because I need the integration process to check the value of `p` after each iteration.

Comment: Do you insist on the state having three components, or would it be sufficient if it had only the two components `S,T`?

Comment: It's enough to have only `S,T` , but I must evaluate `p` in every step to see the value of `k1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def ode(t, TS):
    T, S = TS

    p = -0.2*T + S
    k1 = 0 if p <= 0.01 else 5

    dTdt = 1 - T - k1*T
    dSdt = 0.1*(1 - S) - k1*S

    return dTdt, dSdt

# Solve
TS_start = (0.7, 0.4)
t_span = [0, 3]
sol = solve_ivp(ode, t_span, TS_start, method='RK45',
                rtol=1e-5)
print(sol.message)
print('nbr eval', sol.nfev)

# Graph
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0, :], label='T')
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[1, :], label='S'); plt.legend();
plt.xlabel('time');
```

[image: result graph]

It seems to be a difficult problem to solve numerically. Other tested solvers don't converge, and the use of events is not helpful as they are more and more frequent near the steady state solution

Edit: indeed changing the flipping value to -0.01 instead of +0.01 leads to a limit cycle solution, for which the `events` method of `solve_ivp` is working:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def ode(t, TS):
    T, S = TS

    p = -0.2*T + S
    k1 = 0 if sign_change(t, TS) <= 0 else 5

    dTdt = 1 - T - k1*T
    dSdt = 0.1*(1 - S) - k1*S

    return dTdt, dSdt

def sign_change(t, TS):
    T, S = TS
    p = -0.2*T + S
    flip = -0.01
    return p - flip

# Solve
TS_start = [0.3, 0.1]
t_span = [0, 5]
sol = solve_ivp(ode, t_span, TS_start,
                method='RK45', events=sign_change)
print(sol.message)
print('nbr eval', sol.nfev)

# Graph
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0, :], '-x', label='T')
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[1, :], label='S'); plt.legend();
plt.xlabel('time');

for t in sol.t_events[0]:
    plt.axvline(x=t, color='gray', linewidth=1)
```

now the solution is:

[image: solution with p=-0.01]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a system with self-sustained oscillations. For some reason, this doesn't show it. everything stays flat after one cycle. How did you find out that the events are more frequent near the steady solution? Numerically? Also, does the values of P over time are stored? Thanks!

Comment: Making the jump smooth with a steep slope via `k1 = 0.5*(k1lo+k1hi + (k1hi-k1lo)*np.tanh((p-flip)/1e-6))` or short `k1=2.5*(1+np.tanh((p-0.01)/1e-6))`, method "Radau" takes about 1000 function evaluations, while "RK45" takes half a million.

Comment: @ValientProcess: When the flip is at 0 I see jigsaw oscillations. Are the parameters here the same as in the original simulation? Is the time span the same? // You will need to reconstruct the values of `p` and `k1` from the returned values.

Comment: Yeah, with -0.01 there is a clear limit cycle. The parameters should be adjusted, it's nondimensionalized so the time is less of an issue. Thank you!

Comment: the coarse solver (rk45 with defaut tolerance) is working too when using -0.01 as the flipping value, showing the limit cycle, I added the solution using the events method of Solve_ivp (it is also working without it)...

Answer (score 3):

To reconstruct the values of `k1` and `p` after the integration, put this computation into an extra function

```py
def kp(T,S):
    p = -0.2*T + S
    k1lo, k1hi = 0, 5
    flip = -0.01
    k1 = 0.5*(k1lo+k1hi + (k1hi-k1lo)*np.tanh((p-flip)/1e-8))
    return k1,p
```

and call this then in the ODE derivatives function

```py
def ode(t, TS):
    T, S = TS
    k1,_ = kp(T,S)
    dTdt = 1 - T - k1*T
    dSdt = 0.1*(1 - S) - k1*S
    return dTdt, dSdt
```

and later after the integration to plot along the solution components

```py
T,S = sol.y;
k,p = k1(T,S);
```

Using the per comment corrected threshold value `flip=-0.01` one obtains indeed oscillating behavior.

[image: plot of solution and decision variables]